# How to view the existing files of a drive binary copy?

Tags: dd, binary

**Greetings**

I've been recently studying the concepts of compression and copying in Linux.

When I've been introduced to the [`dd`](https://ioflood.com/blog/dd-linux-command/#:%7E:text=The%20%27dd%27%20command%20reads%20input,tasks%20such%20as%20copying%20disks.&text=In%20this%20example%2C%20%27dd%27%20reads%20from%20%27input.) command, I have found it quite useful, so as an exercise, I bit-by-bit copied my fat32 thumb drive into a file.

What I've been naively expecting was the ability to directly access the files inside the thumb drive, which is not possible after a bit-by-bit copy, indicating the actuality that the `dd` command might be only useful for generating [**iso**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_disc_image) images for a file system.

I'm currently looking for a command that makes reading the files from a bit-by-bit copy possible, does such a command exists?

Comment: Did you attempt to mount the image of your thumb drive?

Answer (score 2):

If you did `cp /dev/sdb1 file.img` (or the same with `dd` though using `dd` would be counterproductive here especially with the default block size), to copy the raw contents of the first partition of the `sdb` device into `file.img`, `file.img`'s content will be a VFAT-formatted filesystem image, like a *`iso`* image will contain the image of a ISO9660-type filesystem so what you need to access files within is something that understands the VFAT file system, just like you need something that understands the ustar/pax file format to access files within a `tar` archive.

The Linux kernel does understand the VFAT file system, that's how you're able to access files on `/dev/sdb1` after you mount `/dev/sdb1` on some directory.

You can also mount a file system contained in a plain file, by using a `loop` block device.

```
sudo losetup -f --show file.img
```

Will create a loop device (using the first `f`ree one whose path it will `show`), something that acts like a block device but is backed by a regular file.

You can then mount it with `sudo mount /dev/loopXX /some/directory`.

If you don't intend to make any modification to the image, you should probably mount it read-only by adding `-r` or `-o ro` to that command, or even make the loop device itself read-only by passing the `-r` option to `losetup`.

These days, `mount` can do the `losetup` by itself if you pass the `-o loop` option:

```
sudo mount -o loop file.img /some/directory
```

And with even more recent versions, you can even skip the `-o loop` as it will assume you want to loop-mount if trying to mount a regular file:

```
sudo mount file.img /some/directory
```

Other things that understand the VFAT file system are the GNU `mtools`, where you can use the `COMMAND.COM`/`CMD.EXE` MS-DOS/Windows commands (`dir`, `type`, `copy`...) prefixed with `m` (for Microsoft/MS-DOS) to access files in VFAT-formatted disks or disk images.

```
mdir -i file.img
```

Will list the contents of the root directory of the VFAT  filesystem contained in `file.img`.

Comment: If the image _must_ remain a bit-by-bit copy, then mounting it as read-only may be prudent, although I'm not 100% certain this prevents altering the image file.

Comment: @Kusalananda. Thanks, I've added it now. As long as the image is VFAT (as opposed to ext4 for instance where a journal could be replayed), I would think the image wouldn't be altered. Making the loop device read-only would guarantee it (but could prevent mounting an unclean ext4 FS for instance).